# Добавление сервиса в фоновую задачу

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, scheduler

Реализую старт фоновой задачи по [примеру](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

В классе TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable мне необходимо добавить еще доп сервис с реализацией нескольких методов из другого проекта

```
public class SchedulerSettings : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    protected readonly IProxyService _proxyService;
    public SchedulerSettings(IProxyService proxyService)
    {
        _proxyService = proxyService;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
       var a =  _proxyService.GetListProxyIp();
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Но при загрузке Program.cs падает ошибка

System.AggregateException: "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Web.Settings.Scheduler.SchedulerSettings': Unable to resolve service for type 'ApplicationCore.Interfaces.Services.IProxyService' while attempting to activate 'Web.Settings.Scheduler.SchedulerSettings'.)"

Как правильно реализовать запуск фоновой задачи при старте asp.net приложения?

Comment: А вы точно не забыли реализацию для IProxyService зарегистрировать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov забыл, всё верно... Спасибо!